# Continue if else in inline for Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have not been able to find the trick to do a continue/pass on an if in a for, any ideas?. Please don't provide explicit loops as solutions, it should be everything in a one liner.

I tested the code with continue, pass and only if...

```
list_num=[1,3]
[("Hola"  if i == 1 else continue)  for i in list_num]
```

Output of my trials :

```
[("Hola"  if i == 1 else continue)  for i in list_num]
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


File "<stdin>", line 1
    [("Hola"  if i == 1 else pass)  for i in list_num]
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax



File "<stdin>", line 1
    [(if i == 1: "Hola")  for i in list_num]
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're returning 'continue' as the result of a ternary operation. A if B else C is a ternary operator, it evaluates B and returns A if true, C if not.

Comment: You can't use *statements* in conditional *expressions*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can replace each item in list:

```
>>> ['hola' if i == 1 else '' for i in list_num]
['hola', '']
```

Or replace when a condition is met:

```
>>> ['hola' for i in list_num if i == 1]
['hola']
```

Comment: Also for replacement, I'd like to offer this alternative: `["hola" * (i==1) for i in list_num]`

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks for your answer, the second one is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This was the answer, thanks @Meyer

Answer (score 3):

It is important to remember that the ternary operator is *still* an operator, and thus needs an expression to return. So it does make sense you cannot use statements such as `continue` or `pass`. They are not expressions.

However, using a statement in your list comprehension is completely unnecessary anyway. In fact you don't even need the ternary operator. Filtering items from a list is a common idiom, so Python provides special syntax for doing so by allowing you to use single `if` statements in a comprehension:

```
>>> list_num = [1, 3]
>>> ["Hola" for i in list_num if i == 1]
['Hola']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a guard to a list comprehension statement it goes at the end. Also, since it is a guard there is no `else` clause:

```
list_num=[1,3]
["Hola" for i in list_num if i == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use filtering feature in the list comprehension. Consider the following example:

```
['Hola' for i in list_num if i == 1]
```