# Pass statement in one-line Python if-else statement

Tags: python

I want to write a single-line if-else statement that does nothing if the first condition is not met. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575239/continue-if-else-in-inline-for-python/44575300) is very similar to what I want to achieve, but I want my code to `pass` (do nothing) when the condition is not met.

In other words:

```py
# Some list
cols = ['firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname', 'dob', 'gender', 'salary']

# Filter elements in list
[col if 'name' in col else pass for col in cols]

# Expected output
> ['firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname']
```

After reading the comments in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114003/error-when-trying-to-use-pass-keyword-in-one-line-if-statement), I also tried skipping the `else` statement:

```py
[col if 'name' in col for col in cols]
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The syntax I want to reduce to a one-liner is:

```py
my_list = []
for col in cols:
    if 'name' in col:
        my_list.append(col)
```

Can the above code be reduced to a one-liner?

Comment: `[col for col in cols if 'name' in col]` ?

Comment: You dont need an explicit else statement, just remove it from your list comprehension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pass` is a statement, not a value, so it cannot be used in a conditional expression.

You want to use the filter clause of the list comprehension.

```
[col for col in cols if 'name' in col]
```

It is somewhat unfortunate that the keyword `if` is used in three distinct syntactic constructs (`if` statements, conditional expressions, and the iteration construct shared by list/dict/set comprehensions and generator expressions).

Answer (score 2):

iiuc:

```
my_list = [col for col in cols if 'name' in col]
```

if statements need to come **after** the for loop when using list comprehension.

Comment: It's not an if statement; calling it that just reinforces the confusion between the various constructs that all use the `if` keyword.